# How to run ABCDE when I insert music CDs

Tags: 11.10, automation, cd-ripping

I used to have ABCDE run automatically and rip a CD when I put it in my computer. 
I did this by selecting ABCDE for when a CD is inserted through the Media tab in Nautilus but this option has been removed in 11.10.

There isn't an option to add a custom command in the menu on removable media so how would i go about getting ABCDE to run when i insert a CD.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by

1. Making a .desktop file for abcde in the /usr/share/applications/ folder
2. Editing defaults.list, changing the

> > x-content/audio-cdda=

to

> > x-content/audio-cdda=abcde.desktop

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to be working fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

In the long run I think one should refrain from editing defaults.list (the one in /etc/gnome/
Better to edit or add lines in ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list